# Kong Gateway with JWT token for UI

Tags: user-interface, jwt, node-red, gateway, kong

We have configured the Kong gateway with JWT authentication.
To load our UI through the Kong gateway, we pass a JWT token, which enables successful retrieval of the UI. However, we are encountering authorization issues with the resource files that the UI loads. These files remain unauthorized.

Is there a configuration option available that allows us to automatically add the token to all resource files if the initiator possesses a valid JWT token?

FYI - https://github.com/Kong/kong/discussions/11148

Comment: You are very unlikely to get a different answer than the one Nick gave when you opened a Node-RED issue.

Comment: @hardillb Is it valid and secure to enable cookie-based authentication on Kong Gateway?